# time complexity of following recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science, recurrence

> I have a recurrence relation as following :

```
T (n) = n * T (n/b) + f (n)
```

then, how to find it's time complexity?

> Can i compare 'a' with n in this relation?

How can i use Masters theorem in this recurrence relation?
Can i assume 'a' as n ,if so it gives 'b' = n and it becomes a = b = n ? is that all right ? T (n) becomes constant as a result. is that possible?

Comment: Something in your reasoning is not correct. How did you arrive at b=n? And how does this lead to T(n) is constant?

Comment: More details would be helpful.

Comment: @Henry if we divide the array into  n parts, then the smallest size of each array will be 1 .so n/b =1 . hence b should be n?  i am just asking

Comment: @vibhanshukumar Maybe you have some background information you did not share. For example, I don't see an array in the question, neither do I see something being divided. From what is in the question, `b` is just a free variable and nothing allows to make any assumptions about it.

Comment: @Henry, Sir i am talking about  merge sort algorithm on an array and i am making a comparison based on it..where a is the number of division in each step during recursion  and b is a constant, such that n/b gives the size of each next divided  part in recursion

Comment: @vibhanshukumar If you split the array to `b` pieces, `n/b` elements each, shouldn't the recurrence relation be `T(n) = b * T(n/b)`?

Comment: This expands to a summation of powers of `n` and `b`, which may not have analytical solutions.